# Prove that $(n!)^2$ is greater than $n^n$ for all values of n greater than 2.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

This problem , I assume can be proved using induction, however I am trying to find another way.

Is there a simple combinatorial approach? One notices that $(n!)^2$ is equal to the number of permutations of size n squared, and that $n^n$ is the number of redundant combinations where there are n spaces and n choices.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use Starling approximation of $n!$ ? This will make your life quite easy.

Comment: I'm sure you can - I'll have a look into it? I took this question from an introductory book for combinatorics, so I think there will be a simple way to prove it? Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not combinatorial, but note that
$$(n!)^2=\prod_{k=1}^n k(n+1-k).$$
(We are in essence using the "Baby Gauss" trick.)
But if $k$ is not $1$ or $n$, we have $k(n+1-k)\gt n$.

Comment: Thanks for your help- could you please explain how you achieved the formula? I'm slightly confused?

Comment: We have $(n!)^2=(1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n)(n\cdot (n-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1)$ (I have reversed the second factorial). This is $(1\cdot n) (2\cdot (n-1))\cdots (n\cdot 1)$. Just like finding $1+2+\cdots +n$ by reversing and adding term by term, the usual trick for finding $1+2+\cdots +n$, except in our case we get inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

divide $(n!)^2 > n^n$ by $n!$ to get

$$n! = 1 \times 2 \times \ldots \times (n-1)  \times n > \frac{n}{n} \times \frac{n}{n-1} \times \ldots \times \frac{n}{2} \times \frac{n}{1}$$

It is a bit of simple algebraic manipulation to show that each term on the lhs is greater or equal to the corresponding term on the rhs, or $\frac{n}{n-k} < k+1 $ for $k \in \overline{0, n-1}$